# Where I can find gcc-42-5666 package for mac os x?

Tags: ruby, macos, gcc, xcode4.2, osx-mountain-lion

I installed command line tools for Mountain Lion. But I would like to install ruby 1.8.7.

I found tutorial and I have to install `brew install apple-gcc42` but i get error:

```
=> Downloading http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404
Error: Download failed: http://r.research.att.com/tools/gcc-42-5666.3-darwin11.pkg
```

Anybody could share with us with this package?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are interested into a [OSX GCC Installer](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer)

Comment: It is not recommended to install osx-gcc-installer if you already have Xcode installed.